# A good C++ programming enviornment for Mac OS X

Tags: c++, qt, xcode4, text-editor, textwrangler

I have tried Xcode, textwrangler and Qt. I like textwrangler the best but it doesn't support C++, i.e. compiling, and checking syntax. Can you please recommend a good editor for me?

I didn't like Xcode because it guesses what function you are typing and it's not helping me learn the syntax.

Comment: You can turn off auto complete in xCode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you probably need to separate learning the language from learning a tool.

XCode is probably the best integrated development environment for the Mac and you will come to appreciate its autocompletion feature as it saves you a lot of typing!

If you *really* don't want it (and I suggest that you do!) then you can turn it off:

Goto XCode->Preferences->Text Editing

and uncheck 'suggest completions while typing'

Comment: *XCode is probably the best integarted development environment for the Mac* which is such a shame really... When I had to chose between Eclipse and XCode I felt like I was deciding who to vote for in a presidential election.

Comment: @Dave and Ed S. What about eclipse?

Comment: Nothing wrong with eclipse and I use it for Java dev, webapps and the like but for C, C++ and Objective C apps for the Mac I'd go for XCode. Then again, there's always TextEdit and gcc... ;-)

Comment: @DaveDurbin: Or MacVim and gcc :)

Comment: Or Sublime Text and gcc. Or Aquamacs and gcc. Or ed and gcc.

Comment: +1 for not turning off the completions. Programming isn't about remembering how to spell functions or which header file a function is in, it's about understanding what code does and producing code that does what you want. Tools help you get rid of the cognitive overhead that is the necessity of serialising code into machine-readable text.

Answer (score 1):

Try Eclipse:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

or

CodeBlocks:
http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: I have made but the worst of experiences with C language support for eclipse. Copy and paste in the editor had absurd timing issues, making me constantly paste the wrong text. It was necessary to turn off all code completion and indexing features or the machine would run hot and be unresponsive for half a minute every few minutes while typing, probably indicating the garbage collector fighting a river of temporary memory allocations. I would still force quit eclipse about once per day when it froze completely with moderate CPU load for some other reason.

Comment: The worst problem is that it *does* work for mini projects but scales horribly, effectively luring projects into a trap as they grow.

Answer (score 1):

I just started learning C++ on a mac as well. I like using Xcode to write and run the program since it does a good job of organizing all of the files for the project. Also, it will make learning objective-c easy if that is ever a goal.

I do suggest turning off the auto complete and the live error detection to improve your learning and debugging skills. I turned both off and have struggled at times but I believe that it has increased my understanding.

Best of luck either way!